# Rejecting the next lot probability problem

Tags: probability

The question is:

> A purchaser of electrical components buys them in lots of size 10. It is policy
> to inspect 3 components randomly from a lot and to accept the lot only if all 3 are not
> defect. Assume that 30
> percent of the lots have 4 defective components and 70 percent have 1
> defective component. What is the probability that the electrician will reject the next lot sent to him?

The answer key shows:
[image]

We know $P(A) = P(A|A1)+P(A|A2)= P(A \cap A1)/P(A1) + P(A \cap A2)/P(A2)$

How is $P(A \cap A1)/P(A1)$ equal to the left term above or $P(A \cap A2)/P(A2)$ equal to the 2nd term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numerical answer is correct but the answer key's notation is off. It should be $$P(A) = P(A \cap A_1) + P(A \cap A_2) = P(A | A_1) P(A_1) + P(A | A_2) P(A_2) = \dots$$ and then the stuff with binomial coefficients.

Comment: One more question. When the question says Assume that 30 percent of the lots have 4 defective components and 70 percent have 1 defective component does this mean that all lots have either 1 or 4 defective products (no lots existwith 0 or 2 or 3 or 5 etc defective products)? I imagine this is true otherwise the procedure given wouldn't work? I just thought this distribution was a little weird if this is the case.